# Multer is not processing file upload in typescript-node.js

Tags: node.js, typescript, multer

```
import multer, { FileFilterCallback } from "multer";
import { Request } from "express";
import { randomBytes } from "crypto";
const fileStorage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req: Request, file: Express.Multer.File, cb) => {
    // if I add absolute path for "images", it would be stored in db as absolute, so when I retrieve the path for the <img src=""/> src would not accept because it requires "/images/

    cb(null, "images");
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, randomBytes(4).toString("hex") + "-" + file.originalname);
  },
});

const fileFilter = (
  req: Request,
  file: Express.Multer.File,
  cb: FileFilterCallback
) => {
  if (
    file.mimetype === "image/png" ||
    file.mimetype === "image/jpg" ||
    file.mimetype === "image/jpeg"
  ) {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb(null, false);
  }
};

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(multer({ storage: fileStorage, fileFilter }).single("image"))
```

Same code was working for js but when I converted to Typescript, it breaks. when I submit the form, it is spinning, means multer is not passing it to next middleware.

When I pass absolute path it works, but the issue with absolute path, it will save the absolute path to the database and when I retrieve it `<img src="/home/...">` absolute path will be returned and it won't display the image:

```
const mainFile = path.dirname(process!.mainModule!.filename);
const imagesPath = path.join(mainFile, "images");

const fileStorage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req: Request, file: Express.Multer.File, cb) => {
    cb(null, imagesPath);
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, randomBytes(4).toString("hex") + "-" + file.originalname);
  },
});
```

I edited `ts.config.json` but still get that error:

```
    "baseUrl": "./src"
```

Comment: Any chance your dependency versions changed during the update?

Comment: @Matthias  I did not change the package.json so current installed packages should do the same work? When i submitted the form, page is spinning, that means it is not calling next()

Comment: @Matthias I updated the question. it works with absolute path but not with relative path

Comment: I don't know anything about multer, sorry...